# Printer printing in inverted colors in monochrome

Tags: drivers, 20.04, printing, scanner, canon

I have a Canon Pixma G3010 inkjet printer connected through Wi-Fi, no USB cable on Ubuntu 20.04.

Whenever I print something in monochrome, the print is an inverted version of the file. For example, if i print a simple word document with black text on white background, the printer prints white text over black background, and literally covers the whole paper with ink except where the text is.

I tried downloading some generic canon printer drivers- as explained [here](https://itsubuntu.com/how-to-install-canon-printer-driver-in-ubuntu-20-04/) but didn't change anything- a reboot also does not fix it.

The color printing works fine. The problem only occurs with monochrome mode.

How to fix this? IS there a fix?

Also, scanning does not work on the printer I installed the scanning drivers as well, as mentioned in the previous link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been facing the same issues inverted white text on black background when selecting Greyscale with a Canon MG5750. It looks like a bug that should be reported to Launchpad so that a proper fix can be implemented in the printer driver.

In the meantime I would suggest testing out different drivers with your printer.

#### Use 'driverless' Driver

**Go to Setting then Printers, click the cog next to your print and select *Printer Details*:**

[image: cog menu -> printer details]

Then click the *Search for Drivers* button:

[image]

I got the following driver installed:

[image]

A quick test with this driver fixed the issue.

### Use Gutenprint Driver

Alternatively use a driver selected from the Gutenprint database:

[image]

Remember to pick the driver that matches your Canon Pixma model.

[image]

This gives me an alternative *CUPS + Gutenprint* driver to test out. I actually added it as second printer so I could easily compare and test the two drivers.

[image]

So far this is working as it should do with Greyscale/Monochrome printing however there might be other printer options that different driver work better with. I will update post if find anything further to help.

Comment: I actually stopped printing monochrome and just printed color for a long while.  Unfortunately the driverless method didn't work for me, but the gutenprint drivers are working very nicely, i am able to print monochrome now, hpwever, i clearly remember trying those drivers and still printing inverted, so i guess it just got fixed or something, anyways thank you very much for your answer. Also i want to ask, is there any way to use the scanner part of the printer?